# Why the output of given code is coming as 1,13,3?

Tags: c#

Code:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
int i = 1;
arr[i++] = arr[i] + 10; 
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", arr));
```

As per my understanding, the third line can be broken in two statements i.e.

- `arr[i] = arr[i] + 10 => arr[1] = arr[1] + 10 => arr[1] = 2 + 10 => arr[1] = 12`
- `i++`

Output should be

> 1,12,3

However, output is coming as

> 1,13,3.

Comment: The left hand side is evaluated first to figure out where to store the result, i.e.: `arr[1] = arr[2] + 10;`

Comment: Dude, arr[i++] = arr[i] + 10; for i=1: arr[1] = arr[2]+10; i=2

Comment: Why not simply using `arr[i] = arr[i] + 10; i++;`? Sometimes people making life difficult for themselves

Comment: I completely agree with you. I can modify the code but I want to know reason behind the above output.

Comment: What is unclear about @RenéCarannante's explanation?

Answer (score 2):

`arr[i++]` takes `i` as `1`, so it becomes `arr[1]`. Then `++` increments `i` so the next time it is referenced, it's value is already `2`. So the line can be rewritten as:

```
arr[1] = arr[2] + 10;
```

This is where the `13` is coming from.

Comment: when i++ will be evaluated? Is it after the complete statement execution or after first use?

Comment: It will be evaluated when you access the array element (`arr[i++] = ...`). The evaluation has two steps: it returns the current value which is initially `1`, then its value is immediately incremented by one. So the next time you access `i` its value will be already `2`, even when it's on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are reusing the value of i

try this => add the value before incrementing

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
int i = 1;
int result = arr[i] + 10; 
arr[i++] = result;
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", arr));
```

Comment: This code will give output as 1,12,3. However, my question is why the above code is giving 1,13,3 as output. Thank you.